# expo closes when i use Alert.alert()

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

Description

I have a submit button and i use this function to handle the response. When i use the Alert.alert() api, it automatically closes expo without any warning.

Expected Behavior

I expected to see an alert pop up on the simulator
What action did you perform, and what did you expect to happen?

Observed Behavior

Expo immediately closes on the phone or simulator

Environment

Expo CLI 3.13.1 environment info:
System:
OS: macOS 10.15.3
Shell: 5.7.1 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 12.14.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.21.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.13.7 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
IDEs:
Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.6010548
Xcode: 11.3.1/11C504 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
expo: ^36.0.0 => 36.0.2
react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.1.tar.gz => 0.61.4
npmGlobalPackages:
expo-cli: 3.13.1

Iphone 11 simulator and also on expo physical iphone x

Reproducible Demo

```
import {Alert, Button, } from 'react-native';
const submitButton =  () => {
    Alert.alert('error', [{ text: 'Ok' }]);
 }

//inside return func
<Button title="Submit" onPress={submitButton} />
```

Answer (score 3):

It crashed, because you have not Passing 'message' . You have to write message whether it's empty or not .

```
    syntax of Alert :- static alert(title, message?, buttons?, options? type?)

    yes. we knew that message Parameter is optional , but still you have to pass it when you use Alert.alert(), might be it is expo error .
```

1) Solution

```
const submitButton =  () => {
    Alert.alert('error','', [{ text: 'Ok' }]);
 }
```

2) Solution

```
const submitButon = () => {
    alert('error', [{ text: 'Ok' }]);
}

It will solved your problem
```